# Разработка под iOS в Windows

Tags: delphi

Есть ли сенсорные функции в Delphi

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "сенсорными функциями"?

Answer (score 1):

Есть, начиная с 2010 версии. Основной класс - TTouchManager и все, что с ним взаимосвязано.